# C# WebClient HTTP Basic Authentication Failing 401 with Correct Credentials

Tags: c#, http-post, webclient, basic-authentication, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to automate configuring a wireless router's SSID and Password via [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [webclient](/questions/tagged/webclient).  The router has no API that I know of.  It's an unbranded chinese router.  The web config seems to be the only option for configuration.  It uses [http-basic-authentication](/questions/tagged/http-basic-authentication) (you browse to the IP address of the router and get a generic dialog asking for username and password).

I've used Wireshark to get the headers and form fields that the [http-post](/questions/tagged/http-post) requests use when I manually update the SSID and Password (two separate forms).  I then attempted to use [webclient](/questions/tagged/webclient) to emulate those [post](/questions/tagged/post) requests.

Here is a snippet of code that I am using to attempt to save a new SSID (NameValueCollection is defined elsewhere):

```cs
private const string FORM_SSID = "http://192.168.1.2/formWlanSetup.htm";
private const string REF_SSID = "http://192.168.1.2/formRedirect.htm?redirect-url=wlbasic.htm&wlan_id=0";
private NameValueCollection mFields = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty, Encoding.ASCII);

public string SaveConfigResponse()
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = REF_SSID;
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-US";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "192.168.1.2";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Connection] = "Keep-Alive";
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mFields.ToString()).Length.ToString();
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(config_user + ":" + config_pass));
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
            //wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "admin");
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadValues(FORM_SSID, "POST", mFields));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

This results in an [http-status-code-401](/questions/tagged/http-status-code-401) not authorized response.  Is what I'm trying to do just impossible?

---

## UPDATE

Here are the HTTP headers of both the browser post/response and the WebClient post/response.  Again, I tried to match what I saw the browser posting as well as I could with my WebClient post.

Browser:

```
POST /formWlanSetup.htm HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/formRedirect.htm?redirect-url=wlbasic.htm&wlan_id=0
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 192.168.1.2
Content-Length: 524
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: wlbasic.htm
Content-Length: 183
Date: Thu, 23 Oct 2014 18:18:27 GMT
Server: eCos Embedded Web Server
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

WebClient:

```
POST /formWlanSetup.htm HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://192.168.1.2/formRedirect.htm?redirect-url=wlbasic.htm&wlan_id=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: 192.168.1.2
Content-Length: 524
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 401 Not Authorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="AP"
Date: Thu, 23 Oct 2014 18:18:41 GMT
Server: eCos Embedded Web Server
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Again, that was all gleaned from Wireshark.  I'm not very familiar with Wireshark, but I was able to get this far.  If I knew how to properly extract the raw packet data and pastebin it, I would.

## Important New Observations

- The Wireshark captures of the post packets from both Browser and WebClient obviously differ in the order of the headers.  I don't know how significant that might or might not be, though, as the data for each header is clearly the same.
- One stark difference between the packets that I noticed is that Wireshark reports the Browser packet to be significantly larger than the WebClient packet.  Looking at the itemized view, I couldn't find any obvious differences.  I assume posting raw data for comparison would reveal a lot, but again, I don't really know how to do that.
- ***I had a bewildering revelation.***  Despite the response clearly stating '(401) Unauthorized', the post is in fact being accepted by the router!  Driving in to the router's web config after my WebClient post shows that the settings were accepted and saved.

That last one is a biggie.  I find myself in a situation where I can get my config to save with a WebClient post, but I have to ignore a 401 response in order to do so.  Obviously, this is far from ideal.  So close, yet so far!

---

## FINAL UPDATE (RESOLUTION)

I've solved the issue of failing basic authentication, though not with `WebClient`.  I used the suggestion from @caesay and went with `HttpWebRequest` (together with `WebResponse`).  My form posts result in redirects, so I had to allow for that.

This is essentially what I went with:

```
private bool ConfigureRouter()
{
    bool passed = false;
    string response = "";
    HttpWebRequest WEBREQ = null;
    WebResponse WEBRESP = null;            

    // Attempt to POST form to router that saves a new SSID.
    try
    {
        var uri = new Uri(FORM_SSID); // Create URI from URL string.
        WEBREQ = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

        // If POST will result in redirects, you won't see an "OK"
        // response if you don't allow those redirects
        WEBREQ.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        // Basic authentication will first send the request without 
        // creds.  This is protocol standard.
        // When the server replies with 401, the HttpWebRequest will
        // automatically send the request again with the creds when
        // when PreAuthenticate is set.
        WEBREQ.PreAuthenticate = true;
        WEBREQ.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;

        // Mimic all headers known to satisfy the request
        // as discovered with a tool like Wireshark or Fiddler
        // when the form was submitted from a browser.
        WEBREQ.Method = "POST";
        WEBREQ.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
        WEBREQ.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US"); // No AcceptLanguage property built-in to HttpWebRequest
        WEBREQ.UserAgent = USER_AGENT;
        WEBREQ.Referer = REF_SSID;
        WEBREQ.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        WEBREQ.KeepAlive = true;
        WEBREQ.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache"); // No Pragma property built-in to HttpWebRequest

        // Use a cached credential so that the creds are properly
        // submitted with subsequent redirect requests.
        CredentialCache creds = new CredentialCache();
        creds.Add(uri, "Basic", new NetworkCredential(config_user, config_pass));
        WEBREQ.Credentials = creds;

        // Submit the form.
        using (Stream stream = WEBREQ.GetRequestStream())
        {
            SSID ssid = new SSID(ssid_scanned); // Gets predefined form fields with new SSID inserted (NameValueCollection PostData)
            stream.Write(ssid.PostData, 0, ssid.PostData.Length);
        }

        // Get the response from the final redirect.
        WEBRESP = WEBREQ.GetResponse();
        response = ((HttpWebResponse)WEBRESP).StatusCode.ToString();
        if (response == "OK")
        {
            StatusUpdate("STATUS: SSID save was successful.");
            passed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            StatusUpdate("FAILED: SSID save was unsuccessful.");
            passed = false;
        }
        WEBRESP.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StatusUpdate("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    return passed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is what I'm trying to do just impossible?

No, its not impossible. I have had many headaches with web scraping like this over the years because some web servers are picky, and your router interface is likely a custom web server implementation that isnt as forgiving as apache or iis.

I would do a wireshark capture and get the raw packet data that chrome sends (w/ payload etc), and then do the same capture for your application. Make sure the packets are as similar as you can get them. If you still have issues, post the packet captures to pastebin or something so we can have a look.

**EDIT::**

Instead of using the limited WebClient API, try using some lower level items, I wonder if the following code will work for you:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.2/formWlanSetup.htm");
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
request.Referer = "http://192.168.1.2/formRedirect.htm?redirect-url=wlbasic.htm&wlan_id=0";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config_user, config_pass);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
var response = request.GetResponse();
var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string htmlResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I added your code above and passed the uri to the UploadValues  instead of the string.  I now get a WebClient Exception: "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."  Inner Exception: "The 'Content-Length' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.\r\nParameter name: name".  My ContentLength header is wrong now somehow?

Comment: @Solipcyst; Oh, you shouldn't be setting the contentlength header yourself... The framework will automatically set that to the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far.  I've update my post with some interesting new finds.  If you have any quick insights as to how I might extract human readable 'raw' packet data from Wireshark, I'm all ears.  That kind of thing is out of my comfort zone.  The best I can do right now is compare HTTP headers and form data.

Comment: @Solipcyst: Hey, I have a hunch what is wrong, Why are you using the `UploadValues` method to upload an empty `NameValueCollection`? after all, the browser wouldnt set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if there were no values to post.

Comment: I probably wasn't as clear about that `NameValueCollection` as I meant to be.  The list isn't empty.  It's been defined elsewhere prior to this method.

Comment: Thanks @caesay.  I've abandoned WebClient, as you suggested and I've got everything working now.  More info in my original post.  Marking as correct because, while it doesn't resolve the idea of getting this done with WebClient, it does resolve the issue of getting it **done**.  If that's a no no, I'm sure someone can correct.