# HostName of IP Camera

Tags: c#, network-programming, ipv4, dhcp

I have an IP camera hooked up to a router along with other computers. I want to find the IP of the camera which is given dynamically by the router's DHCP server. I ping all of the possible IPs of the router to see which are active. I then want to use the client name to determine if the IP is a camera. However when I use

```
Dns.GetHostEntry("[IP of Camera]").HostName
```

I get a SocketException: No such host is known. The host names for the computers on the router show up, and when I look at the DHCP clients at the router's address it shows the camera client name. I also am able to get the camera's IP and MAC Address through ARP. Is there a way to get the client name instead of the host name?

Also, I have read examples of querying a DHCP server, but it doesn't work on non-Microsoft DHCP servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running Axis camera's, probably the easiest DNS solution is [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS). The other alternative is UPnP.

Comment: I ended up using this method. The camera would broadcast at 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 twice (discovery and request). Then it would contact Bonjour at something like 204.00.00.255 from the IP it was assigned.

Answer (score 1):

DNS and DHCP are **unrelated** systems, by default. DNS is a global hierarchical, federated system with root name servers for .com, .net, .org etcetera, and local DNS servers which act as gateways and caches.

It's unclear how your camera's would show up in DNS. Under which root would you expect to find them?

Now your router may also be playing DHCP server (that's a common combination) and therefore know the local names, but that doesn't mean the router is also the DNS server. That DNS server may very well be located at your ISP.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful! I do not necessarily need them to show up in DNS. I just need some way to identify that they are cameras and not computers/other devices. The only distinguishing factor I think is in the client name there is the manufacturer and I want to get the client name to look for the manufacturer. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know your brand of IP camera's; they do differ a lot. We often use Axis camera's, and they're pretty smart. You can't spot that they're Axis camera's from their hostname, though, because that hostname does dpend on the 3rd-party software they're running. What _is_ reliable, however, is the MAC address prefix (first 3 bytes) because that's a manufacturer-assigned prefix.

Comment: We are also using AxisCameras and in every router we have put them in the client name is Axis[MAC Address]. I liked the MAC address idea as well, but my boss doesn't.

Comment: @SethKitchen: Well, the MAC address is how [Axis itself handles their camera's](http://www.axis.com/support/faq/FAQ2551) which should convince your boss. In particular, check out the Axis IP utility. As for the names that show up in the router, I know that out-of-the-box they indeed show up as Axis-<MACaddr>. But I know at least two ACAP suppliers who'll overwrite that Axis name - and your router **will** show the modified name.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a webclient to access the page on the router with the DHCP clients table if it has the IP->client name mapping you're looking for? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614985/c-sharp-webclient-http-basic-authentication-failing-401-with-correct-credentials) an example to get you started.

Comment: Although this idea seems like it would work, it does not look like the easiest way.

Comment: It's not, but it's the most likely way of accomplishing what you want and you will have learned a few new things along the way, so to me at least, it's well worth the little bit of extra time.